# Trying to suppress TS2339 by suppressExcessPropertyErrors compiler option

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Here is the code:

```
var x = {};
x.test = 'abc';
```

Getting typescript compiler error:

> TS2339: Property 'test' does not exist on type '{}'.

I want to suppress this warning for object literals, I suppose that putting `suppressExcessPropertyErrors` into `tsconfig.json` should solve this.

tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "suppressExcessPropertyErrors": true
    },
    ...
}
```

But nothing changed.. compiler still showing the error.

Thank you for any hints ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I suppose that putting suppressExcessPropertyErrors into tsconfig.json should solve this.

No. It suppresses excess properties in object construction e.g.

```
var x = {};
x = {test:'abc'};
```

> I want to suppress this warning for object literals

You can do anything you want using the `any` type e.g.

```
var x:any = {};
x.test = 'abc';
```

## More

This is called *lazy object initiliazation* and patterns for dealing with it are covered here : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/lazyobjectliteralinitialization

Comment: Thank you for answer, I have found "any" solutions before, but I am looking for more general solution, using config flag would be the best. I thought /read that typescript is "optional" superset, so "you can use standard js" beside it. But this case shows that it seems it is not true.

Comment: @basarat added my 5 cents to this answer

Comment: @Luckylooke Of course you can! Apart from three minor things (enums, namespaces, and an obscurespecial  import= syntax), if you remove the type annotations, you are left with pure ECMAScript. That you have to add types, or turn off times specifically at some places using the `any` type, is why you chose TypeScript in the first place! What's the point of adding types to then turn around and complain that you want to turn them off? Then don't add any! You are not using TypeScript in that case, "just JS"!

Comment: @basarat - Your answer, incl. the link, is missing the performance aspect. Keyword "hidden classes", e.g. in V8. Whenever the properties on an object change internally the JS runtime decides "this is a new class of object" and creates a new internal meta structure representing the object and its properties. So if you start with an empty object and add `n` properties one by one, you end up with `n+1` internal representations of that object, all incompatible to one another (becomes important for internal runtime optimizations).

Comment: @Mörre it was because we have had mixure of legacy code and the new one, and I wanted to typescript to be more tolerant to legacy code.. using typescript features where there are defined, but not complain where there are not.

Comment: @Luckylooke precisely, somehow every genius assumes a typescript project is always made from scratch. Well I'm porting a legacy node server from 2014, to typescript and being able to globally suppress lots of type errors would be good.

Answer (score 0):

I could agree with **@basarat** by some points, but please let me to add some suggestions also.

Declaration object props like this could a make sense by several reasons:

```
var x = {
  test: ''
};
x.test = 'abc';
```

1. You will get intellisense support and in next time when you will call `x` object you will see which properties this object contains.
2. Good for testing. You will be sure that construction of your object will not be changed somewhere in your project and can write tests keep in mind it.
3. You will avoid to overriding your object properties with new ones. It could be if you declare you object as `any` type.

**Explanation**:

```
// origin object x with originProp property
var x: any = {
  originProp: 'abc'
};
// new object with new newProp property
x = {
  newProp:'abc'
};
```

Comment: Sometimes I need to merge some multiple data into one object for REST API request, then I would like to use object literal. Everything is ok until you need some conditionals for several properties.. putting "any" solves the problem, but I suppose typescript is optional, so IMHO it should not push me into "any" solution.. and all not specified objects should be type of "any" by default.